# reactjs - State variable is null when callback in parent component is called from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, scopes

**Edit:** I found the solution as a result of cbreezier's advice, as well as learning more about how the table hook was working (which I had found on YouTube and foolishly did not fully understand). Sending `currentData` back to `ParentComponent` via the props callback was what I took from their answer. However, passing `currentData` to the callback was not working from `tableHooks`. I then realized that while it was able to access the rows, it was not able to access the currentData. Changing `Cell: ({ row })` to `Cell: ({ currentData, row })` did the trick.

If you are trying to figure out a similar issue in your own React app, this may not be the exact answer, but I would suggest understanding cbreezier's answer and hopefully that sets you on your way.

**Original Question:**

I have been encountering an issue for a few days now that appears to be rooted in my inexperience with React and Javascript, but without knowing *what* the issue is, it has been difficult to search for a solution. Here is some example code that somewhat isolates the issue:

```js
export const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState([]);

    const fetchCurrentData = async () => {
        let fetchedCurrentData = await getFunctions.getCurrentData();
        setCurrentData(fetchedCurrentData);
    }

    const handleButtonPress = (row) => {
        console.log(currentData);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ChildComponent data={currentData} handleButtonPress={handleButtonPress} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default function ChildComponent(props) => {
    const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, []);
    const data = useMemo(() => props.data, [props.data]);

    const tableHooks = (hooks) => {
        hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
            ...columns, {
                id: "add",
                Header: "Add",
                Cell: ({ row }) => (
                    <button onClick={() => props.handleButtonPress()}>Add</button>
                )
            }
        ])
    }

    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow
    } = useTable({
        columns,
        data
    }, tableHooks);

    return (
        <div>
            <table {...getTableProps()}>
                <thead>
                    {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {
                                headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                    <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                                ))
                            }
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                    {rows.map((row, i) => {
                        prepareRow(row);
                        return (
                            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                {
                                    row.cells.map(cell => {
                                        return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>;
                                    })
                                }
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The flow is as so:

1. Data is received
2. `currentData` state variable is updated using `setCurrentData`
3. `ParentComponent` is re-rendered
4. `ChildComponent` is also rendered and receives `currentData` via props
5. Additionally, `ChildComponent` receives a function `handleButtonPress` via props
6. `ChildComponent` uses `react-table` (v7.8.0) to display the data, and then via a hook is able to create an additional column in the table, with a button for each row
7. The button is set to call `handleButtonPress` from props onClick
8. Button is pressed and `handleButtonPress` is called

The above flow is working correctly. The issue occurs at the end of this flow, when the function `handleButtonPress` is called from `ChildComponent`, as `console.log(currentData)` logs an empty array instead of the actual state of `currentData`. I have verified that `currentData` is populated before re-render of `ParentComponent`, and that it successfully reaches `ChildComponent`.

Would greatly appreciate some help with this! If I had to guess where I'm going wrong, it's that something about passing the function `handleButtonPress` via props is potentially sending a version of the function before `currentData` is set, but like I said I'm quite inexperienced with React and that's just a guess!

Thanks for reading.

Comment: How are you invoking `fetchCurrentData`? It's not being invoked anywhere in your code example.

Comment: Can you define your function in the main child body like `const func = () => props.handleButtonPress()`, and then pass  `<button onClick={func}...`

Comment: @TusharShahi Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately this does not change the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two pieces of missing information that makes it impossible to answer your question with 100% certainty:

1. How are you invoking `fetchCurrentData`?
2. How is `tableHooks` used and invoked?

However, even without that information, I can give you a pretty good idea about what the issue is.

The first thing to understand is that every time `ParentComponent` re-renders, you are defining a completely new `handleButtonPress` function.

The second thing to understand is that the `currentData` variable in `ParentComponent` changes *identity* after `setCurrentData` is called within the `fetchCurrentData` function. What that means is that it's actually a completely difference variable on the second re-render of `ParentComponent` compared to the first.

The third thing to understand is that your `handleButtonPress` function forms a *closure* around the `currentData` variable. However, because the identity of `currentData` changes between re-renders, the variable being closed over is actually different. In other words, the `handleButtonPress` function from the first re-render has closed over the `currentData` variable from the first re-render, which is stuck as `[]`. The `handleButtonPress` function from the second re-render has closed over the `currentData` variable from the second re-render, which contains your actual data.

Finally, I suspect that `tableHooks` is only invoked *once* during the first render of `ChildComponent`, and that the `props.handleButtonPress` function is the *first* `handleButtonPress` function which is stuck with the first `currentData` which is `[]`.

The solution?

Pass through the relevant data through to the `handleButtonPress` function in the invocation of the function. Ie, change the function signature to:

```
    const handleButtonPress = (row, data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }
```

Incidentally, now that function is a *pure* function - it has no side effects (well, other than logging to console) and depends purely on its inputs. You can move that function to be defined outside of your render loop for a (very small) performance improvement, and a pretty useful way to declare "this is indeed a pure function".

In general, prefer pure functions and avoid relying on side effects to avoid tricky situations like you encountered here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I (quite naively) omitted the code that actually invokes `fetchCurrentData` as the actual code that this example was pulled from is longwinded as it relies on an outside API being authenticated. If your suggested solution does not fix the issue, then I will add it, as it may be relevant. On `tableHooks`, I have added that code so that it is clear how the `react-table` package is being used. Thanks again for your answer, I appreciate the time you've taken to explain things for me.